# Quadcopter rotates too slow

Tags: quadcopters, betaflight, blackbox

When I flew my drone yesterday, all the manoeuvres I did felt really slow. I then went into the OSD and changed the rates a bit. The drone then acted as it should, but when I then changed back it still felt fine.

When reviewing the blackbox logs afterwards I noticed that the gyro only registered around 340 deg/s rotation at full stick deflection (See the last part of the bad blackbox log)

After going into the OSD to change what I said above, the rotation speed was 900 deg/s at full stick deflection, as it should be with the rates I have.

To clarify a bit: It felt like I was using rates that were much lower than they actually were. The problem disappeared when I went in to the OSD menu and out again, but the next day I had the same problem again. It is not a major issue as it is easily fixable, but I would be glad if I could get some help to figure out what the problem could be.

The flight controller uses betaflight 4.1.

[Here is a link to the blackbox logs.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10j8z4HjYo0QTffGxYLVt1UB5Cbe4Mi2l?usp=sharing)

Comment: Perhaps I'm parsing your post wrong, but I'm not clear on what your question is - perhaps why are the rates slow, or something about the gyro? Would you mind clarifying? Thanks.

Comment: It felt like I were using rates that were much lower than what I actually had. When the drone should have rotated at 900 deg/s, it only rotated at 340 deg/s. So, my question is what could cause that to happen.

Comment: Does it have a compass? If yes, than disable it for this test. After that, go into Betaflight Configurator and test if the 3d view of your quad (right after pressing connect) corresponds with the actual movements (one full rotation irl is one full rotation in the 3d view). To be clear - I don't know how I would go about the problem after that (no matter whether it works or not), but it might help others with troubleshooting.

Comment: It matches perfectly, so the gyro seems to be working perfectly. Could it be a software issue? Maybe I should try updating to 4.2 and see if that helps

Comment: What's your transmitter? Is it possible you bumped the D/R switch and dropped your dual rates? Spektrum in particular I believe has these set up as default

Comment: It's a qx7s. But the issue might have been solved by updating the FC, will have to do some more testing though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem had two different reasons; two screws that held the flight controller were a loose, and there was likely a problem with the connections between the gimbals and mail board on the transmitter.

The screws that were loose were both on the same side, which caused the FC to "lag behind" the movement of the quad and thus giving false values to the PID-controller. At least that is my theory.

The problem with the transmitter was not as obvious, but I whan looking at the reciever tab in Betaflight Configurator, I noticed that the roll channel acted almost as if it was smoothed. Even if this wasn't visible in the radio I still tried to unplug and replug the connectors to both of the gimbals, something that was recommended on a few forum threads I found.